# MCU damaged after FLASH->OPTR register changed

Tags: stm32

I have changed STM32G431CBT6's default BOOT0/PB8 pin disable via changed FLASH->OPTR register
nswboot0 bit from factory default 1 to 0, however after that I have already damaged (or something else such as locked) 3 MCUs.

Now connect with STM32CubeProgrammer, it's reject with below messages.

16:37:24 : Disconnected from device.

16:37:25 : ST-LINK SN  : 50FF73064986495117442387

16:37:25 : ST-LINK FW  : V2J37S7

16:37:25 : Board       : --

16:37:25 : Voltage     : 3.24V

16:37:25 : SWD freq    : 4000 KHz

16:37:25 : Connect mode: Normal

16:37:25 : Reset mode  : Software reset

16:37:25 : Device ID   : 0x468

16:37:25 : Revision ID : Rev Y

16:37:25 : UPLOADING OPTION BYTES DATA ...

16:37:25 :   Bank          : 0x00

16:37:25 :   Address       : 0x40022020

16:37:25 :   Size          : 20 Bytes

16:37:25 :   Bank          : 0x01

16:37:25 :   Address       : 0x40022070

16:37:25 :   Size          : 4 Bytes

16:37:25 : UPLOADING ...

16:37:25 :   Size          : 1024 Bytes

16:37:25 :   Address       : 0x8000000

16:37:25 : Read progress:

16:37:25 : Error: Data read failed

Regards,

Tiger

Comment: SLOVED : use STM32CubeProgrammer to change RDP to AA

Comment: you can answer your question.  An answered question will gain more attention and solve somebody's similar problem.